# What is openMDAO's reasoning for returning 'None' for self cancelling units

Tags: python, python-3.x, openmdao

I've setup an Explicit Component model...

one of my outputs is a ratio:

```
    self.add_output('diameter_over_thickness', units='mm/mm')
```

Upon the class being initialized, openMDAO assigns the units to this output as `None`.

[openMDAO .list_outputs() output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iYGK.png)

Why not `unitless` ? I feel it would be a more effective representation...

Yes I could just assign it to be `unitless` but I do not want to do this. It becomes problematic when you're using openMDAO's get_val() function and a dictionary of predefined units you can call from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of OpenMDAO V3.20 I would say this is more of a legacy behavior than an active choice. the `unitless` unit didn't exist early on AND we thought that variables with no  unit defined (which defaulted to None) should be compatible with variables that were defined as `unitless`.

There is a connection rule that allows variables with units to be connected to other variables that have `None`. One of the key motivations for this is that often times ExecComp I/O is defined without units and it is very convinent to be able to connect dimensional quantities to them.

However, that same rule does not apply to `unitless` variables. In that case, we understand that the user has actively said there are no units and hence a connection to a dimensional quantity should not be allowed.

So there are some semantic differences between `None` and `unitless`. However, I can see the argument that `mm/mm` should be treated as `unitless` and not None. A change like this is backwards incompatible though and would require a [POEM](https://github.com/openmdao/poems) to be written and approved before an implementation change could be made. I suspect the dev team would welcome a POEM on this subject.